# X11 resource freeing (in particular Screen objects)

Tags: c++, x11, xlib

I am currently working on a project where I occasionally need to use X11 functions directly. Coming from a windows world where everything is extensively documented, I am having some trouble finding and groking the relatively sparse linux documentation.

For instance, if I have the code:

```
Display* disp;
if (!(disp = XOpenDisplay(NULL))) {
    return;
}

Window root = DefaultRootWindow(disp);
Screen* scr = XDefaultScreenOfDisplay(disp);

XCloseDisplay(disp);
```

I know that XCloseDisplay will clean up `Window root` since it destroys all windows and resource IDs.

What I don't know is whether or not I need to manually `XFree` `Screen` objects returned from X functions like `XDefaultScreenOfDisplay` as per the example.

Any information on this case or even a generalized rule for when to use Xfree would be extremely helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Raw X, like the Windows SDK is a C interface.

There are about 7 manuals for X-Windows like http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9781565920026.do (Xlib Programming Manual) and https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/x-toolkit-intrinsics/9780937175620/ (X Toolkit Intrinsics Programming Manual).  These are have been around since 1992.  Like Windows, they are full of examples.  Alternatively there is the internet - just type the command, most of the pages are online.

The manual pages will tell you whether a command needs freeing or not.

The man page for XDefaultScreenOfDisplay does not mention freeing so there is no need for it.

If you look at the man page for XGetVisualInfo, it will say that you can free the structure returned usings XFree.

Comment: I know the man page doesnt explicitly mention it, but the Xlib manual states "You must use XFree to free any objects that were allocated by Xlib." So I am left to wonder if if the `Screen*` returned by `XDefaultScreenOfDisplay` has been alloc'd by the function call or if it is essentially a static member of the `Display*`. Hence my confusion.

I guess I will learn to trust that if the man pages dont say to do something, its because you dont need to do it, not because the maintainers expect you to know to do it.

Comment: The philosophy I follow is **if the man page doesn't tell me to free, I don't free**.  It seems to work.  It is typical Unix philosophy - it only complains or highlights information if something is wrong or different.  If nothing is wrong or it is standard behaviour, it doesn't tell you about it.

Comment: @cup Sadly your second link is broken. Would it be possible that you add some information on which book you originally linked to?

Comment: @PhilippLudwig It is volume 4.  I've updated the answer

Answer (score 2):

> Applications should not directly modify any part of the Display and Screen structures. The members should be considered read-only, although they may change as the result of other operations on the display.

This implies that that these structures are managed by XLib and one should not 
`free` or `XFree` them. Freeing a structure means the memory it used to occupy can be allocated for other data and eventually overwritten.

Comment: HA! right there on page 9 lol. I cant believe I didnt think to search for "screen struct".

Comment: However, for Displays there is `XCloseDisplay`. So I wonder if there is something like `XCloseScreen`.

Comment: It might not be the case though, since I ran valgrind on a small test program which acquired a `Screen*` pointer via `XDefaultScreen` and valgrind reported no leaks.